# Restore a Google Apps Script deleted for mistake

Tags: google-apps-script

I have wrote a Apps Script for my Google Sheet.
I activate some triggers to schedule some  functions.
I add a bad trigger and I want to delete IT, I clicked on ALL Triggers page :
https://script.google.com/home/triggers

and inadvertently I have cliked on the name of project on the list of triggers.
Then I have clicked on the trash sure to delete the trigger but It delete my Project !!!

Possible that the trash page is empty and I have lost all my project with a click ?
https://script.google.com/home/trash

Comment: If you delete the trash it gave you a dialog on the bottom to provide with a last chance opportunity to recover the deletion.  If you didn't that opportunity then it's gone for good.  Get us to that fact that you lost and start rewriting it.  Note I have that saving script backups is very easy with Apps Script API.  You save entire projects as JSON files

Answer (score 0):

When deleting a project you get an alert adverting you of it.

[image: Delete forever]

As mentioned on it, if you have deleted the file, is gone forever.

Comment: yes, it was that alert, but I have thinked that it was the trigger not the project

Comment: Then if that was the project, it is gone. Deleted forever

Comment: Same thing happened to me, I thought I was deleting the trigger not the script. Usability issue.